# Asyncio task cancellation

Tags: python, python-asyncio, cancellation

This is a test script I created to better understand task cancellation -

```py
import asyncio
import random
import signal
import traceback

async def shutdown(signame, loop):
    print("Shutting down")
    tasks = [task for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks()]
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
        try:
            await task
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Task cancelled: %s", task)   
    loop.stop()

async def another():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def some_other_process():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return "Me"

async def process(job, loop, i):
    print(i)
    task = loop.create_task(some_other_process())
    value = await task

    if i < 1:
        another_task = loop.create_task(another())
        await another_task
    # await some_other_process()

def pull(loop):
    i = 0
    while True:
        job = f"random-integer-{random.randint(0, 100)}"
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(process(job, loop, i))
            i += 1
        except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
            print("Task cancelled")
            break
        except Exception:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
    # asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()       


def main():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        for signame in ['SIGINT']:
            loop.add_signal_handler(
                getattr(signal, signame),
                lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(shutdown(signame, loop))
            )

        try:
            pull(loop)
        except Exception:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            loop.close()
    finally:
        print("Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I can not understand why I see -

```py
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task cancelling coro=<shutdown() done, defined at test.py:6>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
loop.add_signal_handler(
    getattr(signal, signame),
    lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(shutdown(signame, loop))
)
```

Here using `asyncio.ensure_future` you create task for `shutdown` coroutine, but you don't await anywhere for this task to be finished. Later when you close event loop it warns you this task is pending.

---

**Upd:**

If you want to do some clenup, the best place for it is right before `loop.close()` regardless of reason your script ended (signal, exception, etc.)

Try to alter your code this way:

```
# ...

async def shutdown(loop):  # remove `signal` arg

# ...

def main():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:
            pull(loop)
        except Exception:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            loop.run_until_complete(shutdown(loop))  # just run until shutdown is done
            loop.close()
    finally:
        print("Done")

# ...
```

---

**Upd2:**

In case you still want signal handler, you probably want to do something like this:

```
from functools import partial

loop.add_signal_handler(
    getattr(signal, signame),
    partial(cb, signame, loop)
)

def cb(signame, loop):
    loop.stop()
    loop.run_until_complete(shutdown(signame, loop))
```

Comment: Where do I wait for it?

Comment: What I need to do is *cancel* tasks in case of `sigint`, therefore I need the signal handler

Comment: Two problems with latest changes - `RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.` and `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` for `coro=<some_other_process() running at test.py:23`